# How to see the placeholders values of deployed build in XLDeploy

Tags: xl-deploy

Is there any way by which I can see the deployed build placeholders value in xl deploy.

Or else I can open the war files which is in applications?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The [udm.BaseDeployedArtifact](https://docs.xebialabs.com/xl-deploy/8.0.x/udmcireference.html#udm.BaseDeployedArtifact) contains a property `placeholders`. As such it should be possible to see the placeholders at the `deployed` level (under infrastructure).